# bitbucket > プライベートリポジトリ > ファイル名からそのファイルを含むリポジトリの探索

Tags: git, bitbucket

[bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)にてプライベートリポジトリをいくつも作っているのですが、いくつかのリポジトリにて同じファイル（例: FolderCopyUnit.cpp )をそれぞれのリポジトリに持たせています。

FolderCopyUnit.cpp という名前がわかっている時に、それを含めているリポジトリがどれかを知りたいと思います。

bitbucketのヘルプなど探したり検索ボックスらしきものを試しましたが、今のところ方法は見つかっていません。

ご存じの方おられますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atlassianのサポートに問い合わせたところ、「そのようなツールはありません」との回答をいただいた。

検索対象としたいリポジトリを全部プルしてから、Windows上でエクスプローラーの検索などを使うことになりそう。